# How to add XML mapping to excel through .NET code?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

How to add XML mapping to excel through .NET code?

I need to add column to excel in xml mapping during runtime., but im finding no head way! .

Comment: Your question doesn't contain nearly enough information for us to be helpful. Please rephrase and elaborate so we can help you better. [Here](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) is a good guide to help you figure out what we need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:  It's capable of manipulating XML that excel understands:

http://www.carlosag.net/tools/excelxmlwriter/